# Can not set Spinner multiline enabled

Tags: android, android-spinner, android-xml

Code for spinner

```
ArrayAdapter<String> cat_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                          this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, spin_cat);
cat_adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.multiline_spinner_dropdown_item);
cat_spinner.setAdapter(cat_adapter);
```

Stackoverflow would not let me post image.Otherwise it would me more clear.
I'm trying my best.

I am trying to make an app in which there is one spinner. I have set ontouchevent to getdata(String actually a long one) from next activity and set it to spinner's 0th item.

Now string is too long for one line so half the string getting cut. Instead it should be displayed in next line. [Problem is for displayed item in spinner, not in dialogue box it opens].

I searched a bit but didn't find a working solution.

Thanks

Comment: use a custom layout instead of `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` while creating adapter for spinner

Comment: @kaushik. I tried with custom layout consisting of a TextView (With android:singleLine="false" set) without any luck.